# Problema con Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript, html

Yo lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el usuario agregue algo en el campo de texto se guarde en la lista al presionar el botón
Gracias de antemano

HTML:

```
<body>
   <input id="tarea "type="text" placeholder="Introduce la tarea">
   <input type="submit" value="Agregar tarea">
   <h1>Mis tareas:</h1>
   <hr>
   <ul>
       <li>Aprender Desarrollo Web</li>
   </ul>
   <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Js:

```
// Seleccionar los elementos HTML que necesitamos
var input = document.getElementById("tarea")
var boton = document.getElementById("boton")
var tareas = document.querySelector("ul")

// Cuando se haga click en el botón
boton.addEventListener("click",function(){
    var tarea = input.value
    var li = document.createElement("li")
    li.textContent = tarea
    tarea.appendChild(li)
})
```

Comment: asi de primeras, tienes un espacio mal puesto entre `id="tarea "type="txt"`. No hay un elemento "boton" en ningun sitio (solo en el javascript).

Comment: @Jakala muchas gracias pero ahora me sale esto tarea.appendChild is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>

Comment: Porque `tarea` no existe tampoco. Existe `tareas`.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes una variable mal escrita
JS:

```
var input = document.getElementById("tarea")
var boton = document.getElementById("boton")
var tareas = document.querySelector("ul")

// Cuando se haga click en el botón
boton.addEventListener("click",function(){
    var tarea = input.value
    var li = document.createElement("li")
    li.textContent = tarea
    tareas.appendChild(li)   //Tenías tarea y es tareas
})
```

Si ya has corregido el id="boton" y el id="tarea" (sin el espacio) ya te debe funcionar.